# set Shell = new (Shell.appliecaton)

Tags: shell, vb6, windows-10

I've been using Shell to unzip a file. Suddenly it stopped working with the error:

"Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface"

If I build it on a Win7 machine, it runs on the Win7 machine but not on Win10. 
If I build it on a Win10 machine it runs on the Win10 machine but not on the Win7 machine. 
An earlier version ran fine on both machines when built on the Win7 machine.

I've carefully compared the .aip build files (Advanced Installer) and they are identical. I haven't touched the code in question for 3 or 4 months.

Here is the Code I'm using (you may recognize it):

{ 
Dim ShellClass  As shell32.Shell
Dim FileSource  As shell32.Folder
Dim Filedest    As shell32.Folder
Dim Folderitems As shell32.Folderitems

```
If sFileSource = "" Or sFileDest = "" Then
    GoTo Zip_Activity_Err
End If

Select Case UCase$(Action)
    Case "ZIPFILE"
        If Right$(UCase$(sFileDest), 4) <> ".ZIP" Then
            sFileDest = sFileDest & ".ZIP"
        End If
        If Not Create_Empty_Zip(sFileDest) Then
            GoTo Zip_Activity_Err
        End If
        Set ShellClass = New shell32.Shell
        Set Filedest = ShellClass.NameSpace(sFileDest)
        Call Filedest.CopyHere(sFileSource, 20)

    Case "ZIPFOLDER"
        If Right$(UCase$(sFileDest), 4) <> ".ZIP" Then
            sFileDest = sFileDest & ".ZIP"
        End If
        If Not Create_Empty_Zip(sFileDest) Then
            GoTo Zip_Activity_Err
        End If                                   
        Set ShellClass = New shell32.Shell
        Set FileSource = ShellClass.NameSpace(sFileSource)
        Set Filedest = ShellClass.NameSpace(sFileDest)
        Set Folderitems = FileSource.Items
        Call Filedest.CopyHere(Folderitems, 20)
    Case "UNZIP"
        If Right$(UCase$(sFileSource), 4) <> ".ZIP" Then
            sFileSource = sFileSource & ".ZIP"
        End If

        Set ShellClass = New shell32.Shell  <--- Here's where it fails

        Set FileSource = ShellClass.NameSpace(sFileSource)     
        Set Filedest = ShellClass.NameSpace(sFileDest)     
        Set Folderitems = FileSource.Items     
        Filedest.CopyHere Folderitems, _
            NoUserInterfaceIfErr + _
            NoConfirmOfNewDir + _
            YesToAll + NoProgBox               
     Case Else
End Sele
```

}

Comment: The mystery KB 3123862 patch updated Shell32.dll a month ago on your Win7 machine, might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is probably to use late binding.

So use `Set Obj = CreateObject("Shell.Application")`

Late binding is a conversation.

YourProg: Hi shell, do you have a `namespace` command?

Shell: Yes I do, It's command number 5.

YourProg: Please do command number 5 - here are the parameters

Shell: Here's the return data, if any.

Early binding your program is compiled with both the GUID and to jump to 5th offset in the vtable.

Comment: Shell32.dll seems to break binary compatibility at the slightest sneeze post-XP.  Blame the .Net pall cast over all things Microsoft, sheer laziness, or incompetance but it is what it is.  Late binding is your only defense since they've relegated this API to the "for scripting" ghetto.